# Can't log into StackExchange sites after importing cookies into browser (cookies not portable)

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, login, cookies

When switching from Chrome to Firefox I accepted FF's offer to import my Chrome cookies.

(This was stable/release versions of Chrome 24 and Firefox 18 or 19 on Win7.)

After this I found that I could no longer log into any of the SE sites.  When I attempted to log in, the site would recognize me and display a message indicating that I was being automatically logg'ed in, but when the page refreshed I was still not logged in.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that SE cookies are not portable between browsers (FF and Chrome, at least).

If you do find yourself in this situation the solution is to delete all StackExchange cookies.

Options --> Privacy --> Remove Individual Cookies

Then use the search bar to find the cookies for the SE site you want to use and use the 'remove cookie' button to delete them.

This is simple enough and is probably one of the first things a user should do when they encounter a problem like this, but might not be practical for less advanced users of the non-tech sites.  So, I think it would help if cookies could be made portable, or if login could fail with a message that lead novice users in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

We rotate cookies fairly frequently as part of normal security...therefore sharing one between two browsers won't really work...nor should it.

This is behaving normally, just log in on any additional browsers - don't depend on cookie imports.

Comment: I'm not surprised to hear that it shouldn't work, but I still think there is a problem with the way it doesn't work - that can't be 'by design'.  The user will never be able to log-in again until they delete the SE cookies - and I think novice users won't figure that out.